# What is best for multiple word replacement in a large text file, sed or awk?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a list of words to be replaced in a large  text file. I wanted to know which command sed/awk would be best to do the operation. Also does sed/awk read text file line by line or loads the entire file in memory ?

Comment: This question has two problems: it's a) too broad and will b) lead to opinion-based answers...

Comment: Even though benchmarks should be run to answer this sort of question convincingly, I think most people would agree that sed is faster than awk, and both read line by line.

Comment: @r_31415 `awk` reads records and fields.  It depends on the values of the internal variables `RS` and `FS` what these are. By _default_, a record is a line and a field is a whitespace-delimited word.

Comment: I've closed this question since it is unclear. It is difficult to answer generic questions like these without seeing examples of what operations are needed to be carried out. It is easy to write slow code in both `awk` and `sed`, and it's easy to write unreadable code in both, so you may conclude that either is "better". Also, replacing words is something that templating engines and macro processors do, so it's not clear at all why you want to compare just `sed` and `awk`. Also, depending on the format of the document (JSON, YAML, etc.), some other tool completely may be "better".

Comment: @Kusalananda You're missing the point of this question. It is about which tool provides better performance when processing large text files, and that's the motivation that led to asking whether both tools read files "line by line" (not whether it is read by fields, records or anything else).

Comment: @r_31415 There is nothing about performance in the question. My comment was about the fact that yes, `awk` reads lines, but only because the default record type is a line.

Comment: @r_31415 On the other hand, neither `sed` nor `awk` reads lines. The expose lines to the user code, but they probably read blocks of 4k or more at once. It doesn't matter, as the OP does not say anything about what metric "better" should have, or what implementations they are comparing, or what code these implementations should run.

Comment: It is not difficult to see that when people ask about reading large files, most likely, "best" refers to performance/speed. It is always trivial to reformulate the question in terms of technicalities and conditionals, but that's rarely useful for the OP.

Comment: @r_31415 Well, I could ask about reading a VCF file (which is a bioinformatics format which usually is quite large), and think I want to do it with `sed` or `awk`, while the correct way of doing it, which would also be the fastest, is to use SAMtools or some other bioinformatics software, _depending on what it is I want to do_.  So we're back at square one. We can't answer a question about the "best" (quickest, safest, easiest, etc.) way of doing something when we don't know what they want to do.

Comment: @r_31415 Also note that it is now 16 hours since they asked. Doing whatever they need to do would likely take less than 16 hours regardless of what tool they use, and the difference that the choice of tool/language would make to the amount of time to solve their problem is insignificant.  Unfortunately, we still, after 16 hours, don't know what they want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a clear: *it depends*.

1. It depends on how you define »best«. Faster? Easier to write? To read? To maintain? More portable? More elegant?
2. It depends on the exact task. `sed` may generally be faster as r-31415 claims in a comment, but depending on how the replacements are defined (how are words limited, can parts of words match?) the limited possibilities of `sed` may require a couple of operations that let it fall behind `awk`.
3. It depends on the implementation. Both commands work line-by-line, both use regular expressions for the replacement, so the regexp engine is likely to determine execution speed. How well is it optimized? Does it use precompiled patterns? It could even depend on the hardware it is running on! The BSD implementation could run faster on ARM, while the GNU implementation is faster on AMD64.

Let me ask one question back: Why do you want to know?

Comment: Good answer. I think it is fair to say "best" means "faster" when it comes to large files.